# Ruby on Rails User Confirmation not updating a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my application I have a user confirmation process. When a user signs up four things happen:

1. An account_status_id is set to 1 (unconfirmed)
2. The user is signed in (now current_user exists)
3. A new_account_confirmation_token is generated
4. A confirmation email is sent to the new user with a link that includes the new_account_confirmation_token

I initially tried to handle the confirmation link with this method. It finds the user without issue and the code flows through the update_attributes! method, however it wasn't updating the account_status. From what I can tell it is due to the fact that the current_user object exists, therefore the user Im trying to update is already "in memory". Is that correct?

```
  def new_account_confirmation
    @title = "Account Confirmation"
    logger.info("User is not logged in")
    @user = User.find_by_new_account_confirmation_token(params[:confirm_id])      
    if @user
      @user.update_attributes!(:account_status_id => 2)
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

My work around is as follows. The code below works but I'd like to know why the code above doesn't work.  Why won't it update the account_status?

```
  def new_account_confirmation
    @title = "Account Confirmation"
    if current_user
      logger.info("User is logged in")
      current_user.update_attributes!(:account_status_id => 2)
    else
      logger.info("User is not logged in")
      @user = User.find_by_new_account_confirmation_token(params[:confirm_id])      
      if @user
        @user.update_attributes!(:account_status_id => 2)
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the first set of code updates the row in the database? It looks correct. But yes, i imagine that because the current_user is in memory, it's therefore not updating. Out of curiosity are you serializing the whole user object in the session? Generally it is better to just store the id, and query it on request so you always have the most updated information.

Comment: The first method does not update the row in the database. And I'm only storing the user_id in session, not the entire current_user object

Answer (score 0):

Even if your user is "in memory" as you say, that's no reason for it not to update. I believe your update IS happening but you're just not seeing it because `current_user` is not in sync with `@user`.

I don't know how you're verifying that `@user` is not being updated but if `update_attributes!` is not throwing an error then it's being saved.

Comment: Thanks for you response. That makes sense, but it isn't happening. I'm checking the db from rails console (reload! everything I can think of to refresh it) and it doesn't update the status. Is it possible that @user and current_user are referring to two separate instances of the data and they aren't syncing properly?

Comment: from what i see of your code, it looks like if the user is logged in as user1 but clicks a confirmation link for user2 then they'd be out of sync. you never check if current_user equals @user. but it's easy to check - after your code runs see what `current_user` and `@user` is.